# GoogleSheet Query: Gruop By and Avg on not numeric data

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm quite new to query on google sheets. I'm trying to make avg on no numeric data.
I have data like this:

```
--------------------------------
| DATE        | RATING    |....|
--------------------------------
| 12-03-2020  | Very Good |....|
--------------------------------
| 12-03-2020  | Good      |....|
--------------------------------
| 12-03-2020  | Good      |....|
--------------------------------
| 13-03-2020  | Bad       |....|
--------------------------------
| 13-03-2020  | Normal    |....|
--------------------------------
| 13-03-2020  | Bad       |....|
--------------------------------
| 14-03-2020  | Very Good |....|
--------------------------------
| 14-03-2020  | Normal    |....|
--------------------------------
| 14-03-2020  | Bad       |....|
```

Rating can be: Very Good, Good, Normal, Bad and Very Bad. I would like to
make a group by for Date with avg on Rating, is there a smart way to do it?
I was trying something like

```
=query(MyRange; 'select myCustomToLiteralRating(avg(myCustomToNumericRating(B)) group by A')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: you haven't provided enough information yet. We don't know the range (columns/rows) for the sample data in your post. We don't know what your ellipses to the right of that data mean or whether you want to retrieve other data. We don't know what"MyRange," "myCustomToLiteralRating" or "myCustomToNumericRating" mean (e.g., named ranges, and if so, where? What's in them? Or are they just placeholders trying to describe something in your post?). You will always get the most speedy, efficient and accurate help if you share a link to a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select Col2,count(Col2)/"&COUNTA(B2:B)&" 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  label count(Col2)/"&COUNTA(B2:B)&"''")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Giuseppe, please first read my comment on your initial post. To sum up, there is not enough data in your post for us to know with confidence what you want.

That said, I will take a guess based on my gut. Supposing that your headers in your sample data were in A1 and B1, that your other data were in A2:B, that you *only* want to process that data, and that you are looking for a *word and not a number* for the final result, this formula should work:

```
=ArrayFormula({"DATE","AVG RATING";SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),1,1),SWITCH(QUERY(ROUND(QUERY(FILTER({A2:A,SWITCH(TRIM(B2:B),"Very Good",4,"Good",3,"Normal",2,"Bad",1)},A2:A<>""),"Select Col1, AVG(Col2) Group By Col1 Order By Col1 Asc Label AVG(Col2) ''")),"Select Col2"),4,"Very Good",3,"Good",2,"Normal",1,"Bad")})
```

I will not spend the time to explain how the formula works here, because we don't yet know *that it works at all*. If you try it and it happens to be correct, and if you then would like to know how it works, report back and I'll do my best to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I need a word for the final result. Il will test it as soon as possible and I'll let you know if it works ;).